# selecting a element using tag + id value using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

How can I do and in CSS / jquery selectors ? ex how do I select a jquery element with tag button and id "reg".

Comment: You mean like $('button#reg') ?

Comment: `button#reg` in `CSS` and $('button#reg') in `jQuery`.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: @verisimilitude please post is an answer, and I will mark as answered.

Comment: @nonnb please post is an answer, and I will mark as answered

Comment: If you have the ID, specifying the tag is unnecessary :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDs are for unique DOM elements, so just look for the ID:

```
var button = $( '#reg' );
```

Edit:: If you must:

```
var button = $( 'button#reg' );
```

Answer (score 1):

IDs are the fastest selectors... So if you are actually assigning an elemetent an ID make sure it's unique so you can always select it by the id-selector

```
$('# // <-- id selector - notice the pound sign

$('#reg').  //<-- that's how you select an element by id
```